# Login Process Issues

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class login
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim audit As String
    Dim faudit As String
    Dim connectiontime, active As String
    Dim attempts As String
    Dim server As String = "server=127.0.0.1;user=root;database=spilibrary"
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Dim statement As String
        Dim Userrole As String
        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = server
        conn.Open()
        statement = "select * from user where Username = '" & username.Text & "' and Password = BINARY '" & password.Text & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(statement, conn)
        Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        Try
            Dim found As Boolean
            While Reader.Read
                found = True
                Userrole = Reader.GetString("Userrole")
                connectiontime = Reader.GetString("connectiontime")
                attempts = Reader.GetString("attempts")
                If Userrole = "Administrator" And connectiontime = "Now" Or connectiontime <= TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm") Then
                    MsgBox("Welcome Admin", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "System message")
                    mainform.Show()
                    mainform.Maintenancebtn.Enabled = True
                    mainform.level1.Text = Userrole
                    'Me.Close()
                    Reader.Close()
                    cmd = New MySqlCommand("update user set attempts = '" & "0" & "', connectiontime='" & "Now" & "' where Username='" & username.Text & "'", conn)
                    Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                ElseIf Userrole = "Librarian" And connectiontime = "Now" Or connectiontime <= TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss") Then
                    MsgBox("Welcome Librarian", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "System Message")
                    'mainform.Maintenancebtn.Enabled = False
                    mainform.Show()
                    mainform.level1.Text = Userrole
                    ' Me.Close()
                    'OPAC.show()
                    Reader.Close()
                    cmd = New MySqlCommand("update user set attempts ='" & "0" & "', connectiontime ='" & "Now" & "' where Username='" & username.Text & "'", conn)
                    Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                ElseIf Userrole = "Administrator" And connectiontime <> "Now" And connectiontime >= TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss") Then
                    MsgBox("You're Account has been blocked because of multiple failed attempts", vbCritical, "System Message")
                ElseIf Userrole = "Librarian" And connectiontime <> "Now" And connectiontime >= TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss") Then
                    MsgBox("Your Account has been blocked because of multiple failed attempts", vbCritical, "System Message")
                Else
                    MsgBox("You're Account whas been blocked because of multiple failed attempts", vbCritical, "System Message")
                End If
```

Someone please help me with this.. when i hit login button it always reads the first if-else statement i enter which is the Userrole="administrator" even if im logging in my Librarian Userrole. when i try to switch them the It reads the librarian userrole and not the admin even if im logging my admin userrole.. in my database they are declared right. so maybe it's the code. Thank you

Comment: Always use Parameters to avoid Sql Injection.

Comment: You only error protect the code after the data access. You are assuming that there will be no errors connecting or retrieving data.

Comment: `connectiontime <= TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm")` You are trying to compare 2 strings. You realize less than will refer to alphbetical order which will not give you expected results. Date/Time values should be stored as a Date/Time

Comment: everything is fine now i  put parameters thanks to mr. jon roberts

Comment: I do not see any Parameters mention in jon's code. I am speaking of command parameters. If you don't use them you put your database in danger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using brackets in your condition to make it clearer.  Like this:

```
If Userrole = "Administrator" AndAlso (connectiontime = "Now" OrElse connectiontime <= TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm")) Then
```

in your code, it would also match if

```
connectiontime <= TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm")
```

Comment: @glendonnolo that's OK. And has priority over Or so you need to use brackets to override that if that's not what you want.